# Unable to find org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.navigation while migrating RCP application from 3.7 to 4.3

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

I have an existing RCP application which is running in verion 3.7. I am trying to migrate it to 4.3 by including the dependent jars. But after the application is launched I am not able to get any navigation view displayed. I am getting the blow error

```
ERROR: Unable to find Action Set: org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.annotationNavigation
LogListener: ERROR:  >> Exception object is null
LogListener: ERROR: Unable to find Action Set: org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.navigation
LogListener: ERROR:  >> Exception object is null
```

The class which I am including the above two classes is extending ActionBarAdvisor.

Another exception which I am getting is

```
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR: Unhandled event loop exceptionjava.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData cannot be cast to org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillData
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData cannot be cast to org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillData
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.computeChildSize(FillLayout.java:144)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.computeSize(FillLayout.java:122)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSize(Composite.java:235)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.jface.action.ControlContribution.computeWidth(ControlContribution.java:55)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.jface.action.ControlContribution.fill(ControlContribution.java:106)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.jface.action.ToolBarManager.update(ToolBarManager.java:353)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer$6$1.run(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:351)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.RunAndTrack.runExternalCode(RunAndTrack.java:56)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ToolBarManagerRenderer$6.changed(ToolBarManagerRenderer.java:348)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:110)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.processScheduled(EclipseContext.java:334)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.set(EclipseContext.java:348)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.ExpressionContext.addVariable(ExpressionContext.java:108)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationService.changeVariable(EvaluationService.java:140)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.EvaluationService$3.sourceChanged(EvaluationService.java:115)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.ui.AbstractSourceProvider.fireSourceChanged(AbstractSourceProvider.java:89)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.access$10(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:1)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider$6.handleEvent(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:780)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1554)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1391)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1416)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1397)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.filterProc(Shell.java:755)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterProc(Display.java:1566)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(Native Method)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(OS.java:2288)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3361)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
08/08/14 03:06:02  LogListener: ERROR:  >>      at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
```

Answer (score 0):

These action sets are in the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` plugin. Make sure you have that included in the RCP build.

Comment: Yes. I have already added this in my build.xml file. I am getting one more exception apart from this. Not sure wehther both are related. Have edited the question to include the other exception as well.